# Facebook PHP SDK - post content to a page's wall

Tags: facebook, post, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page

Can I post something to my Facebook page' s wall with PHP?

I can post to my own wall by giving permissions in the Auth dialog for the applications, but I can't see the Auth dialog page if I'm logged with my page's name.

Comment: For the record you can't use a canvas app when logged in as a page. But of course you can post to page wall, using the method posted by @DMCS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can post to your page's wall if you ask for the `manage_pages` permission and then grab the access token for that page from the `me/accounts` results.